# Deepspeed multi-node training- errno: 98 - Address already in use

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, distributed-computing

I am trying to run multi-node training using Deepspeed. I have 2 nodes each with 1 GPU. When I launch the script one of the nodes hangs on "Initializing TorchBackend in DeepSpeed with backend ncc" while waiting for the other node, but the other node gives the following error:

> RuntimeError: The server socket has failed to listen on any local
> network address. The server socket has failed to bind to [::]:7000
> (errno: 98 - Address already in use). The server socket has failed to
> bind to ?UNKNOWN? (errno: 98 - Address already in use).

I have set the master port on both nodes as port 7000. Since both nodes need to use that port, I am confused that I am getting error 'Address already in use'. Isn't that the whole point,that it should be in use by the other node?

This is the script I am running on both nodes. With the only difference that I am running it with node_rank=1 on the second node.

```
> deepspeed --num_gpus 1 --num_nodes 2 --hostfile hostfile --master_addr
> xxx.xx.xx.198 --master_port=7000 \
>           run_clm.py \
>           --node_rank=0 \
>           --deepspeed ds_conf \
>           --model_name_or_path distilgpt2 \
>           --dataset_name shibing624/source_code\
>           --dataset_config_name python\
>           --max_seq_length 512 \
>           --preprocessing_num_workers 128\
>           --do_train\
>           --per_device_train_batch_size 16\
>           --per_device_eval_batch_size 128\
>           --learning_rate 2e-4 \
>           --weight_decay 0.01\
>           --adam_beta1 0.9\
>           --adam_beta2 0.999\
>           --adam_epsilon 1e-6\
>           --warmup_steps 10000\
>           --save_steps 100\
>           --logging_steps 100\
>           --save_total_limit 2 \
>           --dataloader_num_workers 2 \
>           --output_dir /path/to/output_dir \
>           --max_steps 50000
```